# What's an example of a good uninjection in Node.js? (mySQL)

Tags: javascript, sql-injection, node.js, mariadb

I'm hosting a simple MariaDB/mySQL server on my Raspberry Pi. I would like to know whether or not this code is secure enough to reject an injection attempt made by login/signup, etc.

```
function secureUnInject() {
  const str = String(arguments[0]);
  return encodeURI(str.split("\'").join("").substring(0, 250).replace(/(\")/gi, "").trim()) || "";
}

// Example
connection.query(`
INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('${secureUnInject(username)}', '${secureUnInject(email)}', '${secureUnInject(password)}');
`);
```

Is this code good enough? What do people usually use in Node.js to reject these attacks?

Comment: Please use parameter binding instead of building the query as a string. See [How to pass parameters to mysql query callback in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819826/how-to-pass-parameters-to-mysql-query-callback-in-nodejs) and https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @SteffenUllrich great find, I didn't no you could do that. But can't you still pass strings through the parameters? I think it's still prone to an injection

Comment: The very point of parameter binding is that you have a clear separation between SQL command and its parameters instead of having these mixed together into a query string and letting the SQL parser figure out what the command and what the parameters are. That's why no additional SQL escaping is done when using parameter binding.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So that's it? I don't have to run it through anything? I thought it would be a lot harder than that lol